# Which design pattern closely mimic the OSGi?

Tags: design-patterns, osgi

For example, if I want the benefits of OSGi in my application (modularization, dependency injection etc.) without using OSGi, which design patters will I employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two you mentioned are at the top of my list:

1. **Modularity**.  You don't have the benefit of class loader isolation, so you're going to have to use your own conventions to ensure you don't "reach across" into other components.  If you think switching to OSGi is in your project's future, you definitely want to avoid Class.forName, Thread.getContextClassLoader, etc., which don't work well in an OSGi environment.
2. **Services**.  You don't have the benefit of a service registry, which allows components in separate modules to discover and register with eachother while remaining loosely coupled, so you'll want to use something similar.  There is [PojoSR](http://code.google.com/p/pojosr/), but otherwise you could use a dependency injection framework to loosely couple.

Most of the rest of OSGi is what the specification guarantes the framework will do for you (JVM singletons, security, management, dynamism, etc.), so you would be on your own.  It's perhaps easiest to look at the list of [Benefits of Using OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/WhyOSGi) to see what you'll be missing.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  No design patterns or approaches are mentioned.

Comment: Use of modules and use of service registry are patterns in my opinion, and I tried to gives some basic suggestions when not running in an OSGi environment. OP didn't give much detail, but my answer was presumably the detail being asked for...

Answer (score 0):

OSGI provides a LOT out of the box.  If you don't want to use it, I would still suggest using some sort of framework, e.g. Spring.

Spring is easier to set up and has a dependency injection container.  You can of course always do your own dependency injection in the way you create your classes.  There are two ways this is commonly done, constructor injection where the needed classes/objects are passed in constructor arguments on object creation, and setter injection - where the class has setters for each dependency.  Just make sure to set  all dependencies or an object can be in an invalid state.

Modularization can mean a LOT of things depending on how far you want to take it.  As a general rule, programming against interfaces will get you some degree of modularity.  Using a well known software architecture such as MVC and related patterns will get you some of the way there.  OSGI uses the whiteboard pattern vs the publish/subscribe or listener pattern but both fulfill similar needs.  Both these patterns allow extensive decoupling of objects.

If you post what type of things you are trying to achieve, I can help you more.